# Building ffmpeg on Windows

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, cygwin, mingw

I've the source code of ffmpeg and would like to build it in my win7. I've minGW installed on my machine. I found a step by step instruction from this link:

http://www.gooli.org/blog/building-ffmpeg-for-windows-with-msys-and-mingw/

The link 'Download updated bash for MSYS' did not follow. It showed the file is not found. When I try to build the program the way explained in the site, it shows an error:

Unknown option “â€“extra-cflags=-mno-cygwin”.
See ./configure –help for available options.
./myconfig: â€“extra-ldflags=-Wl,â€“add-stdcall-alias: command not found
./myconfig: â€“target-os=mingw32: command not found

From a similar question posted here, I followed the link http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/ but the static build downloaded from the site was corrupted. Pls help.

Comment: How about `Shared` builds? Try FFMPEG frontend tools like WinFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, those instructions are really old, refer to old version of mingw/msys

better, new instructions (visual walk through ) available at http://ingar.satgnu.net/devenv/mingw32/base.html

you install msys, not bash, it comes with MinGW shell, /bin/sh.exe, and you use it to drive configure, just like ingar does with a whole bunch of other projects above

the usual magic incantation is

```
sh configure --enable-static --enable-shared
make test
make install
```